# Altering a table to change time frame [WHERE/ALTER]

Tags: sql, alter-table

Edit: currently running SQuirreL SQL v.3.8.0.

I created, and saved, a table which pulls customer data around a specific time-frame using a `WHERE` statement. How would I got about updating the time frame? I tried using an `ALTER TABLE` Function to change the `WHERE` statement, but get an error message.

Original table

```
SELECT Customer,
AVG(CAST(ItemPrice AS FLOAT)) AS item_price, 
COUNT(DISTINCT(ReceiptIDDesc)) AS number_of_orders, 
SUM(CAST(ItemPrice AS FLOAT)) AS total_spend
INTO Customer_data_A
FROM Tacos 
Where (CAST(PurchaseDate AS DateTime) >= '01/01/2017 12:00') AND (CAST(PurchaseDate AS DateTime) <= '12/01/2017 12:00')
GROUP BY Customer
```

Alter statement

```
ALTER TABLE Customer_data_A ALTER COLUMN * WHERE (CAST(PurchaseDate AS DateTime) >= '01/01/2017 12:00') AND (CAST(PurchaseDate AS DateTime) <= '11/01/2017 12:00')
```

Which gives me the following error message:

Error: Incorrect syntax near '*'.

SQLState:  S0001

ErrorCode: 102

Comment: Tagging with the DB used might get you more relevant answers.

Comment: @Theo what are you trying to accomplish by ur query?

Comment: @msoliman Jiri's point below clarified my misunderstanding. I was trying to update a table I had created, for a different time-frame, which doesn't makes sense. Don't have a complete understanding of the logic behind SQL yet, appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most SQL dialects, the query you've used essentially says "Perform this query and store the result into a new table". There is no relation whatsoever between the new table and the query that was used to get the data for it.

What you might actually want to use is either views (always shows current data for the query given - think "named query") or materialized views (actually stores the data in a table, but user can trigger refresh of the data from fresh result of the query).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking to TRUNCATE the existing data and load (INSERT INTO) the existing table structure?

An ALTER TABLE + ALTER COLUMN would be more used for changing the data types or adding constraints (i.e. Changing an INT column to NUMERIC, or adding a Foreign Key reference).

```
TRUNCATE TABLE Customer_data_A;

INSERT INTO Customer_data_A
(Customer, ItemPrice, Number_Of_Orders, Total_Spend)
SELECT Customer
      ,AVG(CAST(ItemPrice AS FLOAT)) AS item_price
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT(ReceiptIDDesc)) AS number_of_orders
      ,SUM(CAST(ItemPrice AS FLOAT)) AS total_spend
FROM Tacos 
WHERE (CAST(PurchaseDate AS DateTime) >= '01/01/2017 12:00') AND (CAST(PurchaseDate AS DateTime) <= '11/01/2017 12:00')
GROUP BY Customer;
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. This is helpful.